# Image-processing / OCR technique to separate touching characters

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, ocr

I'm attempting to prepare images for OCR by Tesseract.
However certain character sequences touch (due to the serifs on the font glyphs), and this confuses it.

For example `I/U`:

[image]

I notice a bright outline to each character. If that could be replaced with a dark colour the letters would gain some breathing space.

```
    img_grey[img_grey > 100] = 0
```

... But I can't quite make it work.

Is anyone aware of a better technique?

Comment: OCR shouldn't need this

Answer (score 2):

Using OpenCV you could convert it to grayscale, then apply an Otsu's threshold to get a binarized image, and then erode it:

```
import cv2         
import numpy as np    

im = cv2.imread('image.png')
im = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
 
_, th = cv2.threshold(im, 120, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)     

kernel = np.ones((5,5), np.uint8)

# Increase iterations if you want it thinner
eroded = cv2.erode(th, kernel, iterations=2)

cv2.imwrite('eroded.png', eroded)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could try to erode the image, in opencv there is an operation called eroding, it basicly shrinks the character thickness in this case. This should allow some space between the characters but be careful not to over do it or else tesseract might not be able to recognize the character. To can get the right amount of errosion by trial and error.

Refer to this [Link](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.15/db/df6/tutorial_erosion_dilatation.html) for more details.